Is there a term for additional casing that extends above the main fuselage?
There is a Russian term for this, which doesn't sound like a Russian word, гаргрот (something like gargrote in latin letters) which Wikipedia page doesn't have links to other languages (save for Ukrainian). So I am curious, what could be an English or French term for this, if any? And also, what could be possible origin for the Russian term.
A good example is a "hump" that stayed on the back of Douglas A-4 Skyhawk until A-4H modification, where it was removed.

Or that red case on the Kh-58 Soviet anti-radiation missile


There is not a general term for this.
What it is called will likely vary depending on the size, placement, and purpose.  For example, a bump like this that is a part of an original design is likely to be given a more favorable name than something added later.
One term would be a 'blister'.  On the other hand, the F-16's conformal fuel tanks are called just that.
'Protuberance' is a term that applies to just about anything that is not a 'clean' part of the aircraft.  The dictionary definition says it is for things that stick out, but in practice it can include bumps and blisters, as well as antennae, bonding straps, gaps, seams, fasteners, cooling vents, exhaust, etc.  Pretty much anything that adds drag to an aircraft, but that is not a part of the ideal smooth shape.
It seems the Skyhawk hump was not included on early aircraft, and was added to later aircraft to carry additional avionics / electronics.  skyhawk.org is a great resource on the skyhawk.  On that page, they call it the 'hump back'.
The bump on the missile is there to run wires or pneumatic/hydraulic lines past the combustion chamber.  They usually connect the guidance system (in the front) with the actuators for the control system (in the back).  The combustion chamber of the solid rocket motor is a cylindrical pressure vessel and anything that pierces that is a big problem.

I have heard an A4 pilot call this a "camel back." Also included on the A4M.
